# How to send email to users who has changes in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins scripted pipeline. If the build fails I wish to send email to list of users who has changes(commits). I request people to help me to get the list of users and send email only to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the jenkins-pipeline **post task** with the **email-ext** plugin. Please refer to:

- Pipeline **post** section: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/
- **Email-ext** plugin: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/

  - > **culprits:** Sends email to the list of users who committed a change since the last non-broken build till now. This list at least always include people who made changes in this build, but if the previous build was a failure it also includes the culprit list from there.

The pipeline below should solve your problem:

**Declarative Pipeline Example:**

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        ...
    }
    post {
        failure { 
            emailext body: "your email body here",
                     mimeType: 'text/html',
                     subject: "your subject here",
                     to: emailextrecipients([
                         [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']
                     ])
        }
    }
}
```

**Scripted Pipeline Example:**

```
def postFailure() {
    emailext body: "your email body here",
                     mimeType: 'text/html',
                     subject: "your subject here",
                     to: emailextrecipients([
                         [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']
                     ])
}

node {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (e) {
        postFailure()
        throw e
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using scripted pipeline. Is there any way to use this in scripted pipeline

Comment: I am getting an error "No such DSL method 'postFailure' found among steps "